# How to stage and commit from gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

How can I stage changes and commit them from the gitk interface? It is said to be a "repository browser". Does it mean, that it is not possible to stage and commit at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gitk` is a pure browser, not full-blown git client.

You can run git GUI from `gitk`: menu `File`, command `Start git gui`. The GUI allows to create branches, create and amend commits.

To start the GUI from the command line run `git gui`.